# FCM token get refreshed after some time

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an iOS App using Xamarin and integrated FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) for push notifications. Its working fine on development phase, but on beta testing through test flight, the FCM token automatically regenerates or refreshes after some time (in between 5-10 minutes).

```
void TokenRefreshNotification(object sender, NSNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        // This method will be fired everytime a new token is generated, including the first
        // time. So if you need to retrieve the token as soon as it is available this is where that
        // should be done.
        //var refreshedToken = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
        var token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
        WriteLog("Token Refresh");
        ConnectToFCM();

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    }
    public static void ConnectToFCM()
    {
        Messaging.SharedInstance.Connect(error =>
        {
            if (InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token != null)
            {
                var token = InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token;
                //                    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)

                //                    ApnsTokenType = ApnsTokenType.Unknown;
                if (!Settings.DeviceId.Equals(token))
                {
                    Settings.DeviceId = token;
                    Console.WriteLine("Token Updated");
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Token: {InstanceId.SharedInstance.Token}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: So what is the issue here? You need to update the token on your server once it get updated on App.

Comment: In some cases an initial (non APNs mapped) token is generated initially then when the APNs is ready FCM generates a new token that is associated with APNs and returns that via the token refresh callback.

Comment: @GirishM its automatically refreshed after few minutes(less then 10 mins). To update token on server is not a problem i am updating it. But issue is why its refreshed? its working fine on developer mode. i wanted to reached to the problem so that i can solved it and reduced my server call.

Comment: @ArthurThompson its keep on refreshing the token. Not only the first time But after every few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
My Observation is from same API 2 different App is installed that's causing the problem. When i uninstalled one App(which is previous one only bundle ID is different) now its working fine. No token refreshed automatically after few minutes.